# Google sheets script is only pulling formatting from the last column and applying it to all appended rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

My script is meant to pull the conditional formatting from each cell and transfer it to the new appended cells. For some reason it is only pulling the data from the last column and applying it to all appended data as opposed to matching the formatting from the original data. I would greatly appreciate the help as I am very new to this.

Thank you!!

```
function testFormulas() {
      try {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
        var row1 = 1;
        var column1 = 31;
        var row2 = 40;
        var column2 = 6;
        var values = sheet.getRange(row1,column1,row2,column2).getValues();
        var formulas = sheet.getRange(row1,column1,row2,column2).getFormulasR1C1();
        var i=0;
        var j=0;
        var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
        var newRules = [];
        var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    
      
      
      newRules = newRules.concat(rules);
        for( i=1; i<formulas.length; i++ ) {
          for( j=4; j<formulas[0].length; j++ ) {
            if( formulas[i][j] !== "" ) values[i][j] = formulas[i][j];
           
          }
        }
    
      }
      catch(err) {
        Logger.log(err);}
    
         var rowToWriteCounter = 1;
      const firstColumnAvailable = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
    
      var columnToWriteCounter;
    
      for (var row in values) {
    
        columnToWriteCounter = firstColumnAvailable;
        
        for (var col in values[row]) {
    
          //write to the new cell
          sheet.getRange(rowToWriteCounter, columnToWriteCounter).setValue(values[row][col]).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false);
    
          //this part checks for conditional formatting
          for (var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++) {
            var rule = rules[r];
            //Get condition for each rule
            var booleanCondition = rule.getBooleanCondition();
      
            //Get the ranges to which each rule applies and iterate through
            var ranges = rule.getRanges();
            for (var i = 4; i < ranges.length; i++) {
              var ruleColumn = ranges[i].getColumn();
              var ruleRow = ranges[i].getRow(); 
              
             
              //If condition isn't null and edited column is the same as the one in the range, add rule
              if ((ruleColumn == Number(col)+1) && (ruleRow == Number(row)+1) && (booleanCondition != null)) {
                var newRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
                  .withCriteria(booleanCondition.getCriteriaType(), booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues())
                  .setBackground(booleanCondition.getBackgroundObject())
                  .setBold(booleanCondition.getBold())
                  .setItalic(booleanCondition.getItalic())
                  .setRanges([sheet.getRange(rowToWriteCounter, columnToWriteCounter)])
                  .build();
                newRules.push(newRule);
              }
            }
          }
          sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules);
          columnToWriteCounter++;
        }
        rowToWriteCounter++;
      
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: I don't ever use conditional formatting but I'm wondering if the rule ranges can be more that just one cell.  Can they be for example a rectangular array of cells.  If they can then you're extraction of the ruleRow and ruleColumn may not lead to the same distribution of rules  as the original sheet.  Since getRow() and getColumn() just return row and column of upper left cell.

Comment: Say I got rid of the conditional formatting. Would the number formatting follow the same rules?

Comment: I don't know.  Like I said don't ever use conditional formatting.  But I was think that if the ranges don't include sheet names then you might be able to loop through them and reformat the new sheet with the old ranges or perhaps the old ranges converted to A1 Notation.  And even if the do do contain Sheet Names you could replace them after converting to A1.  But again I don't really know.  I'm just kind of throwing out some ideas for you to kick around.

Comment: Would it be alright if you could provide a sample sheet only with dummy values so that we'll be able to do some tests and play around with the script you made?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jdsowD4gYGaF66Xd77uz-EFRYS-J-pi8QjxpmnqqS6E/edit?usp=sharing 

Here is a copy of my sheet with the true values removed.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Try this modification of your script (please see inline comments for updates):

```
function testFormulas() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var startRow = 1;
    var startColumn = 31;
    var numRows = 40;
    var numCols = 6;

    // include alignments
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numCols);
    var values = dataRange.getValues();
    var formulas = dataRange.getFormulasR1C1();

    var newRules = rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
    
    // so we can also include header and other needed values
    for (i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++)
        if (formulas[i][j] !== "")
          values[i][j] = formulas[i][j];

  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }

  const newColumn = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1;

  // write data by bulk
  sheet.getRange(startRow, newColumn, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)

  // separate copy formatting, since setNumberFormats will have an issue on date cells
  // this will take care on alignment, borders, colors, merging, etc
  dataRange.copyFormatToRange(sheet, newColumn, newColumn + numCols, startRow, startRow + numRows);

  // for each range of the rule, modify by adding how many columns
  rules.forEach(rule => {
    var booleanCondition = rule.getBooleanCondition();
    newRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
                  .withCriteria(booleanCondition.getCriteriaType(), booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues())
                  // get string of background object
                  .setBackground(booleanCondition.getBackgroundObject().asRgbColor().asHexString())
                  .setBold(booleanCondition.getBold())
                  .setItalic(booleanCondition.getItalic())
                  .setRanges(rule.getRanges().map(range => sheet.getRange(range.offset(0, numCols).getA1Notation())))
                  .build());
  });
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules);
}
```

I had problems with how to format copies over to the last column from your previous script so I did a complete overhaul with the logic on this one.

And this script `dataRange.copyFormatToRange(sheet, newColumn, newColumn + numCols, startRow, startRow + numRows);` did most of the resolution.